# Flex Maven how to create rsl from third party swc library

Tags: apache-flex, maven, flash, swc, rsl

there are some swc file used in my project,when I compile the project by maven,I have to install the swc to maven repository,like:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=./libs/robotlegs-framework-1.5.1.swc -DgroupId=org.robotlegs -DartifactId=robotlegs-framework -Dversion=1.5.1 -Dpackaging=swc
```

and use like:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.robotlegs</groupId>
            <artifactId>robotlegs-framework</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
            <type>swc</type>
        </dependency>
```

if I want to add the library by RSL, I have to install the swf:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=./libs/robotlegs-framework-1.5.1.swf -DgroupId=org.robotlegs -DartifactId=robotlegs-framework -Dversion=1.5.1 -Dpackaging=swf
```

use like :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.robotlegs</groupId>
            <artifactId>robotlegs-framework</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
            <type>swc</type>
            <scope>rsl</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I don't want to install the swc and swf by shell, is there some solution to unpack the swc file to swf and create rsl, then I just need to use like

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.robotlegs</groupId>
                <artifactId>robotlegs-framework</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.1</version>
                <type>swc</type>
                <scope>rsl</scope>
            </dependency>
```

thanks!!!

Comment: dependency:copy-dependencies,unpack-dependencies,unpack..........doesn't found detail solution.....